# casperjs click on login link is not working

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have created the following casperjs script to login to a website. But, it is not getting logged in.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', function () {
    this.fill('form',
                {
                    'tbxUsername' : 'xyz',
                    'tbxPasswort' : 'zyx',
                }, false);
    this.click('#btnLogin');
});
casper.then(function(){
    this.capture('login_after.png');
    console.log(this.getCurrentUrl());
});
```

This is not showing the logged in page. Still showing the login page with filled data in the form fields.

Am I doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here

```
 this.fill('form',
```

Shouldn't 'form' be a CSS selector, try that with an ID like '#aspnetForm' and see if it works!

Or if that does not work,

rather than using

```
this.then();
```

use this.waitForSelector or this.waitFor since casper does not correctly wait for custom ajax calls. See documentation for more details.

Comment: No luck with #aspnetForm, I will try with waitForSelector or waitFor now.

Comment: I used waitUntilVisible. Now it is working fine. Thanks Kemal.